# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a problem

```
    open: function($type) {
          //Some code
          document.getElementById($type).addEventListener("click", l.close($type), false);
    },
    close: function($type) {
           //There is some code too
           document.getElementById($type).removeEventListener("click", l.close($type), false);
           //^ Recursion & Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    }
```

What I'm doing wrong? Without this click event listener everything is working well. And what is the third parameter doing (true|false)? Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener the third parameter flags whether or not you want the event listener to use event capturing (as oppose to bubbling) on adding, and on removal whether or not the event was added as such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling the `close` function in the `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` when you are trying to pass is as an argument (causing an infinite loop). Instead you should simply pass the reference to the function as follows:

```
document.getElementById($type).addEventListener("click", l.close, false);
```

And:

```
document.getElementById($type).removeEventListener("click", l.close, false);
```

Comment: Thank you. :) But what is the third parameter doing?

Comment: @Krylovech It defines if the handler should be executed during capturing or bubbling phase: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

Or you might have two Javascript functions with the same name.