# Nowjs: [RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

When I start the server on port 8080 it doesn't give me an error, but when I am trying to browse the `http://localhost:8080/nowjs/now.js` the server raises an error:

`[RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded]`
`undefined`

I tried the same with socket.io and it worked fine.

Comment: see this http://javascriptrules.com/2009/06/30/limitation-on-call-stacks/

Comment: Could you include some code samples or even a fiddle that reproduce the problem? If you don't find the source in the process, then maybe we could spot it :)

Comment: even this simple code produces the error:

`var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
server.listen(8080);

var nowjs = require("now");
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);`

Comment: By the way, I'm running it on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, if now.js uses date.js, maybe your issue lies [here](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/detail?id=143). What the link says is that date.js tries to set a toString to Date prototype, but when toString is already defined, you get the **circular reference** mentioned in the other answers.

Basically, they say that in date.js, you change

```
Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString
```

to

```
if(Date.prototype._toString==undefined) {Date.prototype._toString=Date.prototype.toString;}
```

I hope it will help someone. It helped me.

Answer (score 5):

Aadit, have you read the following:

[Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded During a setTimeout Call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8731840/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

[Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497774/uncaught-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-javascript)

So, as you may see the problem seems to be arising because of the an improper use of stack sizes. If you haven't already you may read a bit more about this problem in detail here along with a **possible solution**:
[Maximum call stack size exceeded error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095530/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error)

I don't think it has anything to do with the port, more with the methods/functions in the manner you're interacting/using the stack.

Then again, I may be wrong. ;D

Comment: I already know about call stacks in JavaScript. What I wanted to know was why did the new version of `now.js` suddenly break existing code.

Comment: Is this it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896167/nowjs-running-node-and-nowjs-on-a-hosted-server-error-maximum-call-stack-s

Comment: Nope. Didn't work for me. I'm using node v0.6.18 which is the latest stable version.

Answer (score 4):

I've had two problems with now.js that produce this error message. Hopefully one of them will help you.

**Circular References**

You cannot include any circular references in objects passed into now, or it's extend method will barf. There were some optimizations and workarounds for this and it's now  [listed as an closed issue](https://github.com/Flotype/now/issues/143), but I have run into it.

**initialize() only once**

Second, you may not call `require('now').initialize(...)` twice or the two instances have [a little intellectual conversation](http://www.nuklearpower.com/2001/04/12/episode-015-a-little-intellectual-conversation/) and race each other right out of the stack.

What I did instead was to create `everyone` in app.js and pass it into all my require(...) methods that need to reference the now "pocket".

In /app.js:

```
var conf = {
    everyone: require('now').initialize(app)
    port: 3000,
    // etc...
};

require('./routes')(conf)
// etc...
```

In routes/index.js:

```
module.exports = function(conf) {
   var everyone = conf.everyone;

   return {
       send: function() {
           everyone.now.clientFxn(...);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: ++ for the nuklearpower reference helping explain your answer