# FancyBox not working. Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to use FancyBox in it's simplest form and it's not working -- upon clicking the image thumbnail I'm seeing the following in my developer console: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/site_media/some_image.jpg">
    <img src="/site_media/some_image_thumbnail.jpg">
</a>
```

And the jQuery call to activate FancyBox:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
```

Couldn't be simpler... I'm using jQuery 1.9.1 and FancyBox 2.1.4. Lots of researching has led me to nothing helpful here.

Comment: did you try other things out?...maybe try using absolute paths in the `anchor` such as `http://www.mysite.com/site_media/some_image.jpg`

Comment: No-go on absolute URL... I've tried lots of tinkering... Nothing is working.

Comment: Don't think is a fancybox issue but something else in your code. Any chance to share a link or create a demo page with the issue? ... Check this if it helps http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/19/javascript-stack-overflow-error/ .... or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10966343/1055987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem -- Bootstrap 2.3 broke fancyBox support and they're not willing to fix it. More info here:

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862

Yohn's suggested code change in that thread fixed the problem for me and I haven't seen any side-effects with bootstrap yet. Also interesting-- Bootstrap 2.3 seems to have also broken LightBox with the exact same exception occurring.

EDIT: See Adam's comment below. This Bootstrap bug has been fixed in version 2.3.1

Comment: For anyone wondering, Bootstrap apparently fixed the issue in `2.3.1`. See my comment here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862#issuecomment-14899994

Comment: Yeah I saw they finally fixed it in 2.3.1 a few days ago. Thanks for the update Adam.