# FancyBox 2.1.4 crashes with jQuery 2.0 beta1 + Bootstrap 2.3.0

Tags: jquery, fancybox, twitter-bootstrap-2

FancyBox 2.1.4 crashes with jQuery 2.0 beta1 + Bootstrap 2.3.0
It works with Bootstrap 2.2.2 though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
<title>FancyApps 2.1.4 with jQuery 2.0 beta + bootstrap 2.3.0</title>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0b1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.0.6/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.4/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(".fancybox").fancybox(
    {
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8481/8215602321_69d9939b8b_b.jpg" title="The Trail (Msjunior-Check out my galleries)">
<img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8481/8215602321_69d9939b8b_m.jpg"/>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

1. I don't know if this is a bug or some other error. I couldn't catch the error. Its too fast - by that time the browser showed the image using its default.
2. How do we catch such errors before invoking the browser's default action ? e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: bind a click event to the anchor tag and return false, that way you can see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks. The error is "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded "

Comment: I would start by removing the "helpers" one by one to isolate where the error could be.

Comment: I'd just roll back to the last stable version of jQuery and see if that works.

Comment: it seems to be a bootstrap issue, check https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox not working. Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805473/fancybox-not-working-getting-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)