# Manual call of Fancybox 2 returns 'too much recursion' error

Tags: jquery, recursion, fancybox, fancybox-2

I just installed Fancybox 2 on my website and I am trying to call it manually (by clicking on an image). The error I am getting is 'too much recursion'. I will try to provide as much information as possible because the project is only local.

Here is a list of the javascript files loaded for the given page in the correct order:

- /js/jquery.js
- /js/bootstrap.min.js
- /js/leaflet.js
- /js/jquery.cloud.min.js
- /js/jquery.cookie.js
- /js/jquery.fancybox.min.js

And here is the code (which I think is very simple):

```
function viewImages () { 
    $.fancybox( {href : '223141main_flare_print.gif', title : 'Lorem lipsum'} ); 
}

$('div.image').click(function(){ viewImages (); });
```

Finally, those are the exact errors I am getting as I click the div:

> too much recursion @ ../js/jquery.js:1534
>
> too much recursion @ ../js/jquery.js:2777

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox not working. Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14805473/fancybox-not-working-getting-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded)

Comment: it seems to be a bootstrap issue, check https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Twitter Bootstrap < 2.3.1, it's known to cause this exact issue (I just experienced it, and upgrading bootstrap solved the problem)

More details here: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/519